# Proof about counting sub-sets (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $Ω_{n} = \{1, 2,\dots, n\}$ and for $0 \leq k \leq n$ let $Ω^{k}$
>   be the collection of $k$-element subsets of $Ω_{n}$.
>
> 2. Define the number $S(n,k)$ as cardinality of $Ω^{k}_n$.
> 3. Prove that $S(n,k) = S(n,n−k)$
>
> (Hint: Find a bijection from $Ω^{k}_n$ and $Ω^{n−k}_n$.)

I am kind of new in the world of finding bijections between two sets. I would be glad if someone explains me the general idea to find bijections between sets.

Approach

Proof

Let's consider the example in which $n=5$ and $k=1$

\begin{align*}
\Omega^1 &\leftrightarrow \Omega^{5-1} \\
\{1\} &\leftrightarrow \{2, 3, 4, 5\} \\
\{2\} &\leftrightarrow \{1, 3, 4, 5\} \\
\{3\} &\leftrightarrow \{1, 2, 4, 5\} \\
\{4\} &\leftrightarrow \{1, 2, 3, 5\} \\
\{5\} &\leftrightarrow \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \\
\end{align*}

It can be seen in this example that we can establish a relation between $\Omega^{k}$ and $\Omega^{n-k}$. An element $X \in \Omega^{k}$ can be matched up with an element $ Y \in \Omega^{n-k}$ that doesn't contain any element of A. For example, we can imagine that we have n objects. We put k of this n objects in a bucket X and the other n-k objects in another bucket Y. From this example, we can obviously conclude that the X bucket is an element of $\Omega^{k}$ and the Y bucket is an element of $\Omega^{n-k}$. Let's denote the previous relation as $f: \Omega^{k} \rightarrow  \Omega^{n-k}$.

Now we need to show that $f$ is bijective and to show this we will show it's one to one and onto.

Assume $f$ is not one to one then there exists at least two elements in $\Omega^{k}$  such that they match the same element in  $\Omega^{n-k}$. Let x be the first element in $\Omega^{k}$ and y the second element in $\Omega^{k}$, so there exists an element $z \in \Omega^{n-k}$ such that $(x,z)\in f$ and $(y,z) \in f$. As we know x and y are sets and they have to differ at least by one element, otherwise they are equal. Let call this element p. So if $p \not\in x$ then $p \in z$, but $p\in y$ which contradicts $f$. Therefore, $f$ is one to one.

Assume $f$ is not onto then there exists an element $b \in \Omega^{n-k}$ that is not mapped by any element in $\Omega^{k}$.  b is supposed to be mapped by some subset of k elements and this would imply that such subset doesn't exist but we know that it does hence we ensured that $\Omega^{k}$ covers every subset with k elements, so contradiction. This implies that $f$ is onto.

Comment: fixed it. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: it looks like you are right. I am gonna fix the post hence the point I am trying to make is invalid.

Comment: it looks like I didn't understand all the previous  claims.

Comment: What is true is that $S(n+1,k) = kS(n,k) + S(n,k-1)$

Comment: Something still seems to be wrong with your setup, what's the difference between $\Omega_n$ and $\Omega^k$ and $\Omega_{n}^{k}$

Comment: On the first line, is $\Omega^k$ a typo for $\Omega_n^k$?

Comment: check out the answer below. I looks like Lynn got the point. Sorry for the poor notation. The whole point is n choose k

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Your equation is for Stirling numbers of the second kind. The OP's definition of $S(n,k)$ is different (even though notation used is the same).

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with stirling numbers. It's just n choose k. I was very misleading in the first edition of the post. Now I think I have clarified everything.

Comment: @TheMathNoob I was referring to Brevan's post - the equation in his comment does have to do with Stirling numbers.  I assume Brevan just looked at $S(n,k)$ (which often refers to the Stirling numbers) in the post rather than the definition of $S(n,k)$ in the post.  You are right it is just the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Your answer looks correct, though the last paragraph is not clear.  It might be easier to describe the function as computing the complement - see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a hint: let $n = 5$. What’s the relation between these pairs of subsets?

\begin{align*}
\Omega^1 &\leftrightarrow \Omega^{5-1} \\
\hline
\{1\} &\leftrightarrow \{2, 3, 4, 5\} \\
\{2\} &\leftrightarrow \{1, 3, 4, 5\} \\
\{3\} &\leftrightarrow \{1, 2, 4, 5\} \\
\{4\} &\leftrightarrow \{1, 2, 3, 5\} \\
\{5\} &\leftrightarrow \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \\
\end{align*}

Can you do the same thing for $k \neq 1$?

Comment: the relation that I see is that they are disjoint

Comment: They are disjoint and it's union is the set of n elements. I think I got your point but there is still a lot of holes in my understanding of this. So basically a bijection is any function between the two sets. For example you are defining a bijection by saying that  I am gonna put k elements in the set and the remaining n-k elements in another set and I can see it's onto and one to one. Can you elaborate more on bijections?

Comment: would the generalized bijection be $\{1,2,....,k\}↔\{k+1,.,n\}$

Comment: In my example, given $\{3\}$, applying some process (let’s call it $f : \Omega^k \to \Omega^{n-k}$) gets you $\{1, 2, 4, 5\}$. Can you see what process I’m applying? Can you show that $f$ is bijective?

Comment: Yes, I am now typing a proof to show it's bijective.

Comment: I already put the proof in my original post. How does that look?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the function from $\Omega_n^k$ to $\Omega_n^{n-k}$ defined by $f: A \mapsto A^c$, where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$ in $\Omega_n$. (Recall that the complement of a set $X$ in a universe $U$ is defined to be the set of all elements in $U$ which are not in $X$.) It can be shown that the function $f$ is one-to-one and onto. Hence, the cardinality of the domain and of the codomain are equal, and in fact are equal to the binomial coefficient $n \choose k$.

The cardinality of the set $\Omega_n^k$ of all $k$-subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is equal to the number of ways to choose $k$ elements from $n$ elements, which is ${n \choose k}$.  This number is usually denoted by $C(n,k)$ rather than $S(n,k)$.  Note that $S(n,k)$ usually denotes the Stirling numbers of the second kind, which is the number of ways to partition an $n$ element set into $k$ nonempty sets.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I still don't understand how you can say with such naturalism that the cardinality of the domain is equal to the cardinality of the codomain.,

Comment: Depending on the level of the course/exam where this question is asked, the point of the question might well be to prove that the function $f$ is one-to-one and onto, in which case your more detailed answer would be the better one.

Comment: how can I improve my last paragraph?. I also feel like It's a little bit weak.

Comment: To prove $f$ is onto, suppose $b \in \Omega_n^{n-k}$.  We show there exists an $a \in \Omega_n^k$ such that $f$ maps $a$ to $b$.  Take $a$ to be the set of all elements in $\Omega_n$ which are not in $b$...